# On the closing of a particular question

Tags: feature-request

I would like to reopen the question titled "How can I make voronoi treemaps?" at [How can I make voronoi treemaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838265/how-can-i-make-voronoi-treemaps)

(I may not edit the question because there is nothing wrong with the wording. And I cannot flag it for moderation, because I want to write more than 500 characters in the box. It should be "larger". So, I post here.)

The question titled "How can I make voronoi treemaps?" is a valid question. And some of the corresponding answers are relevant and helpful, but the rest of the answers are irrelevant.

This question is erroneously closed.

I can understand why some people were confused by this question. Although the question is correctly and perfectly worded, some people thought that it was about Voronoi diagrams (a.k.a. Voronoi tessellations).

But this question is not about "Voronoi tessellations". This question is about "Voronoi treemaps". A lot of people are familiar with Voronoi tessellations, but not with Voronoi treemaps. There are a lot of people who do not know what a Voronoi treemap is.

A Voronoi treemap is first and foremost a treemap. But instead of limiting itself to layouts of rectangles, a Voronoi treemap uses circles or polygons (from triangles and onwards). Using any polygons, instead of only rectangles, helps tackle the problem of the "aspect ratio" that plagues conventional treemaps: A desired layout and ordering of areas may lead to rectangles that have one dimension disproportionately larger than the other (something that is ugly and dysfunctional).

Two great papers have been published concerning Voronoi treemaps:

1) M. Balzer and O. Deussen. Voronoi treemaps. In INFOVIS, page 7, 2005.

2) M. Balzer, O. Deussen, and C. Lewerentz. Voronoi treemaps for the visualization of software metrics. In SOFTVIS, pages 165–172, 2005.

The OP (original poster) wants to find an algorithm or library (in Perl, PHP, Ruby, or Python) that creates Voronoi treemaps from (statistical) data that the user will provide.

This question is not only legitimate, but it is also "ongoing": it cannot be answered once and for all. Why? Because as algorithms and libraries that produce Voronoi treemaps become available, people can post them here as answers. And this can continue for ever.

Now, I believe that the person who closed this question made an honest mistake.

But who is going to protect the OP (original poster) from other people's honest mistakes?

Closing a question is an insult to the OP.

Who is going to protect the OP from other people's insults?

I propose that anyone who erroneously closes a question, should lose all his or her points (reputation).

This is how we can tackle the insulting injustice of the erroneous closing of a question (as is the case here).

Comment: No, it is not a valid question. It is **too broad** for the Stack Overflow format. Your reasoning, that later on people can add more answers because the question cannot answered once and for all, supports that case all the more.

Comment: Not only that, but the question shows no prior research effort, it's basically just "give me teh codez".

Comment: `I propose that anyone who erroneously closes a question, should lose all his or her points (reputation).` Too soft, won't fix anything. Corporal punishment is what's needed here

Comment: Taking the closing of a question personally is definitely not how we should be doing things.

Comment: Questions that request large amounts of code (like an entire data structure or a difficult rendering algorithm) be written for them without showing any effort to do so themselves is definitely off topic.  As an aside, brining up a question that's been closed for over 2 years and complaining about it isn't going to get you very far.

Comment: btw - `This question ... is also "ongoing": it cannot be answered once and for all.` that's why it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It's a community policy that has evolved over the past couple of years

Comment: @Dimitrios: your conclusion in that blog looks about right. SO's not for everything. SO's not for everyone.

Comment: Does this question require retagging to discussion/specific-question? I am confused.

Comment: What *feature* are you requesting? Are you seriously requesting that "anyone who erroneously closes a question, should lose all his or her points (reputation)"? Because if so, then that completely justifies the outpouring of downvotes. If you are honestly hoping to open a discussion about a question that you think should be re-opened, then I suggest removing inflammatory comments from your question and retagging the question to [meta-tag:discussion]. You are much more likely to receive a positive reception that way.

Answer (score 9):

"How can I make voronoi treemaps?" is asking us to recommend a library or other resource without showing any prior research, so I reopened it and closed it for that more specific reason. (That reason didn't exist when the question was originally closed.)

> Closing a question is an insult to the OP.

No, it really isn't. Closing a question is about *the question*, not the OP. I've had questions closed and deleted before. Many of us have. Don't take it personally.

> I propose that anyone who erroneously closes a question, should lose all his or her points (reputation).
>
> This is how we can tackle the insulting injustice of the erroneous closing of a question (as is the case here).

Even if it were closed erroneously, that punishment doesn't fit the crime. We can already reopen questions that are closed erroneously, which corrects any perceived injustice. If we start applying harsh penalties for closing questions, soon everyone will be afraid to close any question and we'll spin out of control until we reach [How is babby formed?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080820174408AAZkbcG)

Comment: @DimitriosKalemis What you're proposing is that we should shame people into not closing questions, at the cost of site quality.

Comment: @DimitriosKalemis Honest mistakes can be reversed. There was no honest mistake here. That question was rightly closed.

Comment: @DimitriosKalemis The site that I linked to already exists to accept any question you can think of. Stack Overflow's quality is quite a bit higher because we don't.

Comment: I like turtles.